# disable clipping in edit mode?

Tags: sculpting

Is there a method of making objects so that they cannot clip into each other when moving but instead form around them? I don't mean boolean where an object cuts out of another; more of a soft body hugging a solid object without actually simulating a soft body.

ex:
instead of
[image]

something like this
[image]

as if there's a restriction of points moving through/past each other.

Comment: I'm not aware of any general setting like that, but if you just want a particular interaction between two objects there are a few ways you could rig it, if that would work?

Comment: I'm actually looking for an easier way to sculpt a pliable material that's folding over it's self; specifically in this case a big long tongue. Modeling it by hand probably wouldn't be too difficult and I could also just make it soft and just have gravity do it for me but I wanted to see if theres a method of doing it through some collision setting.